# How to find process ID in WinCe?

Tags: c#, memory, process, windows-ce, pid

I am using an Win Ce 5.0 that was "sliced" by the Manufacturer because of Memory Problems. It starts an application ( an BIN image is made using Platform Builder ) that consumes some memory.

When I want to start debugging it freezes the first application and start the new one that i have been developing ( VS 2008 Pro ). It it not clear for me if the first application consumes some memory ( because i know that some fileds are static ) and some data points are STUBBED.

Main problem is that , Win Ce is only a boot loader that starts the First Application. I can't disable it , switch it or do anything on it, because it is running and it start the ActiveSync ( that's the way that i have communication to my PC / VS 2008 Pro )

Please help me with the solution:
 1. How to find the First Application Process ID ( GetProcessById didn't worked , GetProcessByName is unavailable from the .Net Ce Framework ) 
 2. How to dispose all memory that is loaded by the First Applicaiton - i want to have as much memory available as possible )
 3. Best option it would be to have a watchdog class for testing if the first application is not doing anything ( not starting any process / method )

Willing to offer my points and honor to the person who can help me :)

---

Another problem is with the USB debugging : device has a wrong driver (issue)

USb connection with device
-   After reset – not working ( it detects as AT9S81) - used for flashing device
-   After device – not working ( it detects as AT9S81) - used for flashing device
-   It needs some time to detect as Active Sync (PROTOTYPE--Remember to change idVendor)

Is this a OS problem / device driver / windows 7 problem ?

Comment: Do a google Search on `C# windows CE How to find Process ID by Name` here is one I did for you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/7148cbdc-401a-4727-a9db-fe0c704a303b

Comment: Tried this. All MSDN tips and tricks were tested. I am looking more of a hack because i can't do it "by the book".

Comment: Can you use VS 2008 to develop applications for WinCE 5.0? I remember that for WinCE 7.0 was used VS 2008, for WinCE 6.0 was used VS 2005 and I expect for WinCE 5.0 to be used an earlier version of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you have an older, unsupported CE device that you are trying to make use of?

1. Getting process info is done with the ToolHelp APIs.  You must P/Invoke these with the CF.  The SDF has a full complement of ToolHelp objects of you don't want to write them.
2. You can't "dispose of" memory in another process.  The other process manages its own memory.  You could terminate that process, which would release all of its memory to the OS.
3. How do you propose to know if the other process is "doing anything"?  If it doesn't tell you when it's doing something, it's difficult to know if it's running code (it can be done by using a celog intercept to look at the OS scheduler, but that's pretty advanced stuff and I wouldn't recommend it as a first or even second course of action).

If you have access to run code on the device, I'd recommend modifying the OS to not run whatever app it's running in the first place.  Adjust the HKLM\Init registry entries or whatever is launching it.

Comment: Can you help me with the possible Platform Builder configuration ?